Differences between Trinket and online-python.com
I have this computer program that's supposed to draw a Hand of Mahjong Tiles from a deck:
# imports random
import itertools, random

# make a deck of tiles
deck = list(itertools.product(range(1, 5), range(1,10), range(0,3)))
deckWinds=(list(itertools.product(range(1, 5), range(10,14), range(3,4))))
deckDragons=(list(itertools.product(range(1, 5), range(14,17), range(4,5))))
deck=deck+deckWinds+deckDragons

# shuffles the deck
random.shuffle(deck)

#have a dictionary of suit names and number names
numbers={10: "E", 11: "S", 12: "W", 13: "N", 14: "White", 15: "Green", 16: "Red"}
suits={0: "Wan", 1: "So", 2: "Pin", 3: "Wind", 4: "Dragon"}

#which card is to be drawn
cardNumber=1

# deal myHand
myHand=[]
for i in range(14):
    drawn=deck[cardNumber]
    cardNumber=cardNumber+1
    myHand.append(drawn)
myHand.sort(key=lambda t: (t[2], t[1]))
print(myHand)
visibleHand=[]

# make readable UI version
for i in range(len(myHand)):
    tile, number, suit = myHand[i] # unpack the tuple to have cleaner code
    visibleHand.append(f"{numbers.get(number, number)} {suits.get(suit, suit)}")
print(visibleHand)

On Online Python it works fine, but on Trinket it gives me a series of error messages, starting with SyntaxError: bad input on line 33 in main.py, and when I make that line a comment to see if there are any other problems, it reads AttributeError: '<invalid type>' object has no attribute 'product' on line 5 in main.py. Are there any differences between the two that might cause this?

Very hard to say. This works fine locally too, as well as in Pyodide (as long as you add newlines after each for loop). In other words, who knows what Trinket does.

@AKX By Trinket I mean Trinket.io

Yes, I found it, but I don't much care to sign in there to figure out exactly what they're doing. It's clearly somewhat custom, since they say "Our free Python trinket supports both Python 2 and 3 syntax seamlessly, allowing beginners to use code from either version of the language successfully.", which is not a thing for any off-the-shelf Python.

I'm going to guess that their "seamless" environment chose the wrong version of python.

I bit the bullet and registered on Trinket.io. What they're running as a Python interpreter is nowhere near standard Python, as running
import itertools
print(itertools)
print(dir(itertools))

prints out
<unknown>
['__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'permutations']

IOW, itertools is an <unknown> object, and really only contains permutations (not the rest of what we'd expect itertools to in regular Python world).
import sys
print(sys.copyright)

prints out
Copyright 2009-2010 Scott Graham.
All Rights Reserved.

which is a hint they're running Skulpt, but with the sys.version and sys.version_info values removed so you can't tell more clearly.
So – to answer "Are there any differences between the two that might cause this?": yes, apparently. Are there other differences we can't know about? Very likely.

You didn't need to register. They have a demo on the main page.

Ah, you're right. It only appears after some 5 seconds of animation, I was too impatient.

I think their Python3 trinkets use regular CPython, though.
